# CSS Tab images are not reflecting in selected state

Tags: css

[image]

As you can see in the image there are some tabs called welcome, aa, bb etc. Now the tab color is blue for an image (tab.png) that I have provided but I want to set a different image or no image at the time of selected. Here Welecome is selected and I have provided an image (tab_selected.png) for selected condition but that image is not rendering. Or If I dont provide any image in selected state, still the tab.png is reflecting. What can I do for this ?

CSS:

```
#navigation a {

color:#FFFFFF;
display:block;
font:12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
margin:0 4px 0 0;
padding:3px 10px 4px;
text-decoration:none;
background-image:url(../images/tab.png);

}

#navigation .selected a {

background-image:url(../images/tab_selected.png);
border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
font-weight:bold;
color:#000;
padding-bottom:3px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Which element are you applying the "selected" class to?

If it is the anchor element (a), then your CSS rule should be:

```
#navigation a.selected {
```

Comment: No this is not an issue ! I can write that.

Answer (score 1):

Added double quotes for urls. Try this...

Main issue was found by obfuskater

```
#navigation a {

color:#FFFFFF;
display:block;
font:12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
margin:0 4px 0 0;
padding:3px 10px 4px;
text-decoration:none;
background-image:url("../images/tab.png");

}

#navigation a.selected {

background-image:url("../images/tab_selected.png");
border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
font-weight:bold;
color:#000;
padding-bottom:3px;
}
```

Comment: Make sure that the path actually valid by typing on the browser.

Comment: No ! not working. Is it possible that the tabs has a background image and again I'm setting for selected state ? Can Make selected state full black , because I've tried this also but still the tab.png is reflecting in selected state.